# Send blob object from URL.createObjectURL to another browser

Tags: html, fileapi

I am using the [Camera API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_the_Camera_API?redirect=no) to upload content from my phone's camera. The `URL.createObjectURL` method returns a `Blob` object which I send to another machine and when I try to use that `Blob` as the `src` of an `image` I got this error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: blob:http%3A//136.159.108.19%3A8080/3744c158-6ad6-485c-8fd2-ad16f5c46508
```

What should I do to send the `Blob` object with the image's information to another browser and show this image?

Comment: how exactly are you "sending the blob to another browser"?

Comment: I was just sending it through socket.io. I solved the issue by using `FileReader`. It reads the blob and transform it into a base64 string.